# Why are the below layout parsed correctly in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am testing out my understanding of the layout-parsing function in Haskell report ([Here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3))

I could understand that:

- test case 1 will pass due to good alignment
- test case 2 will fail because "in a + b" is considered a new item at module-level

However, I could not understand why test case 3 would be correctly parsed. So, Questions:

Why will test-case 3 be correctly parsed? 
Which pattern in the LHS of the parsing function L (see [Here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3)) does test-case 3 match?

```
-- test case 1
f_1 = let a = 1
          b = 2
      in a + b

-- test case 2
f_2 = let a = 1
          b = 2
in a + b

-- test case 3
f_3 = let a = 1
          b = 2
                     in a + b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test case 3 matches the parse-error(t) rule.  Because the token `in` is not legal at that point in the `let` block, a `}` is inserted before the `in` to end it.

The parse-error rule can be confusing, but it is also very flexible; using it you can e.g. write Haskell one-liners with rarely any explicit `{}` at all.

Comment: Great tips. Thanks for confirming my guess. Now I am writing `f_4 = let a = 1 \n b = 2 in a + b` and it works smoothly.

Comment: Since one-liners is mentioned here. Would you also help explain how `let x = e; y = x in e’` is parsed? I find it hard to understand the explanation in the report "Note 1 implements the feature that layout processing can be stopped prematurely by a parse error. ".

Comment: @modeller Curious. I suspect that's a typo for "Note 5 implements ...", since note 5 is the one explaining the parse-error(t) rule.  I see it has been that way since the Haskell 98 report. (The 1.4 report doesn't have that much detail.)

Comment: @modeller Anyway, the `{` is inserted by one of the rules referenced in Note 1, but the `}` is inserted by the parse-error(t) rule referenced in Note 5.